# Concurrency of Homo and non-homogeneous linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, systems-of-equations, determinant

Since the determinant of concurrent lines is zero and the solution is non trivial but I get confused when I solved the determinant of non-homogeneous linear equations in three variables which is not equal to zero but the solution satisfying the all three equations simultaneously which means that point is lying on these lines and indicates that these three lines are also concurrent.So, I want to ask that there is any difference between concurrency condition of Homo & Non Homogeneous equations while checking through their determinant.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: "Since the determinant of concurrent lines is zero": Which determinant are you speaking about ? If $ax+by+c=0$ and $a'x+b'y+c'=0$ are concurrent, $\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\a'&b'\end{vmatrix}\ne 0$...

Comment: No comment, half a day later ?